# Where Has The Border Radius Gone on Mouseover

Tags: html, css

I'm making a menu selection bar, and I'm running into a problem when I mouse over. The icon's corners should all be curved, but only the left hand side ones are. 
Here's a demo of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/gfqgcwq5/

From what I can tell, it seems like `inline-block` is the culprit here:

```
.wrapper{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
}
```

I just don't know how to accomplish the inline array without it. I'm not great at css, so if someone could lend me a hand, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: on my machine's browser (firefox) it's working...

Comment: Try `display: inline-table;` on .wrapper, seems to be the solution for chrome (ver. 47.0.2526.73 (64-bit) on Linux).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this one:

```
.icon{
        border-radius:8px;
        padding-top:15px;
        padding-bottom:5px;
        transition:.1s;
        font-size:60px; 
    display: inline-table;
    }

    .icon:hover{ 
        cursor:pointer;
        background-color: #00B1EB;
        color:#fff;

    }

    span#picture > span {
        padding-right:9px;
        padding-left:10px;
        padding-top:7px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
    }


    .text{
        text-align:center;
    }

    .wrapper{
        display:inline-block;margin:10px;
    }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/gfqgcwq5/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Used to this

Define your  `.icon` `display` `inline-block`

as like this

```
.icon{display:inline-block;line-height:60px;}
```

**or you can used to**

```
.icon{display:block;}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gfqgcwq5/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the border-radius is a property (in this case) of the .icon class, if you use the inspector you will see that the wrapper has the proper size and shape[wraper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1FpE.png)

So as the other says the issue is on the display of the .icon class, If your idea is to have more than one .icon elements inside of the wrapper and inline, you should use display: inline-block;, if your call is to have just one per wrapper use display: block;.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta give icon block `display: inline-block` property in order to work !!

```css
 .icon {
   border-radius: 8px;
   padding: 15px;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
   transition: .5s all ease;
   font-size: 60px;
   display: inline-block;
 }
 .icon:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
   background-color: #00B1EB;
   color: #fff;
 }
 span#picture > span {
   padding-right: 9px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-top: 7px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
 }
 .text {
   text-align: center;
 }
 .wrapper {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span id="picture" class="icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span></span>
  <div class="text">PICTURES</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span id="picture" class="icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span></span>
  <div class="text">PICTURES</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span id="picture" class="icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span></span>
  <div class="text">PICTURES</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span id="picture" class="icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span></span>
  <div class="text">PICTURES</div>
</div>
```

Comment: any block level display will do.

Answer (score 0):

Apply padding for the `text div` to allow the entire curve to visible.

```
  .text{
    text-align:center;
    padding:0px 7px;
   }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/gfqgcwq5/25/)